How to install rizsotto/bear on Windows?
Title says it all.
This bear (build ear)

The INSTALL.md doesnt say nothing about Windows
There is no "release" .exe
The CMAKE commands, on INSTALL.md dont work


I think Bear does not support Windows.
However, there is a similar tool, https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb, which does (and has other advantages over Bear such as not requiring a clean build).

Yeah, discored that the hard way, lol. The only sad thing is, compileddb worked on my computer, just installed and, without even creating a compile_commands.json, the lsp started working. But, for some reason, it doesnt work on my laptop. I will probably just format my laptop, since there isnt anything important in it and see if it works.
Thanks.
